# Are there 128-tic Valve servers in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Are there any valve servers at 128 tick for official competitive? I prefer the crisp lagless gameplay than that of a normal 64 tick server.

Comment: I do not think so... and if so you can not choose on wich competitive server you play.

Comment: You cannot chose the server to play on in competitive anyway, so the question is kind of moot.

Comment: can you guys put this into an answer so I can "close" the question?

Comment: @Neffer_23 What research have you done before hand before asking this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently only 64 tick servers for Matchmaking in CS:GO